# twitter-connect-plugin does not work if the twitter native app is not installed

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, twitter

if the native twitter application is not installed in Android the plugin (twitter-connect-plugin) generates a "failed login session" error.

https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin

Any solution for this? Tx!!!